# when text changed inputbox automatically updates next text boxes?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

> ***Follow-Up to:*** [when text changed inputbox automatically updates next 6 text boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815582/when-text-changed-inputbox-automatically-updates-next-6-text-boxes).

I have 7 textboxes. If Top 1 textbox(**Volume All Years**) text changed, text need to be updated in next 6 inputboxes(**Latest 2009 Volume to Latest 2014 Volume**). I need javascript or Jquery for this. I will write Js textchanged() or focuschange() for top 1 textbox. So what should I write in focuschage() or textchanged methods().

I changed little bit in code. Now Html will like below. These textboxes have common CssClass. **volumetextbox**. Can we use this class and change text in all textboxes those have same CssClass.

```
<tr id="row12_136" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Volume All Years</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_136" tabindex="61" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
<tr id="row12_60" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2009 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_60" tabindex="56" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
<tr id="row12_61" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2010 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_61" tabindex="57" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
<tr id="row12_62" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2011 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_62" tabindex="58" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
<tr id="row12_63" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2012 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_63" tabindex="59" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
<tr id="row12_64" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2013 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_64" tabindex="60" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>

<tr id="row12_65" class="RegText">
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-right:20px;">Latest 2014 Volume</td> 
   <td style="width:420px;Padding-left:0px;">
       <input name="12_136" type="text" maxlength="255" id="12_65" tabindex="61" title="Volume All Years" class="volumetextbox" OnKeyPress="javascript:FocusChange();" style="width:300px;" />
    </td>
```

Comment: After your stuff works, spend a few minutes to refactor your html code. Move some stuff like the width and the padding-left definitions into a stylesheet instead of repeating it for every single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an approach like this (not tested):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('input.volumetextbox:first').change( function(){
        var firstVal = $(this).val()
        $('input.volumetextbox:not(:first)').val( firstVal )
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you write depend entirely on what you want in the other 6 text boxes. You might update the values like...

```
document.getElementById('12_60').value = *some calculation*;
```